# HDMI port is not working

Tags: hardware, raspbian-stretch, hdmi, power-supply, pi-3b+

I have been using an RPI3B+ for around 2 months . I used it remotely most of the time. Recently, when I was trying connect it with a monitor via HDMI to VGA converter , it didn't work at all. I inserted the sd card properly and I could connect remotely as well .I've tried with different monitors , different converter .
 I followed [This Tutorial](https://howtoraspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-hdmi-not-working/) to fix the issue .But no luck. I've even tried with reinstalling the raspbian . 
I am using raspbian desktop version for os , a 2.4 amp power supply ,ADATA 64 GB sd card ,HDT11 sensor .
My question is , 
Is this a hardware problem ? Is there any solution?
what could be the reason behind this ?
my config.txt

```
 # For more options and information see
 # http://rpf.io/configtxt
 # Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for 
 details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels 
visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if 
console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's 
size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being 
output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio 
work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

 # uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, 
 blanking, or
 # no display
 #config_hdmi_boost=4

 # uncomment for composite PAL
 #sdtv_mode=2

 #uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
 #arm_freq=800

 # Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware 
 interfaces
 #dtparam=i2c_arm=on
 #dtparam=i2s=on
 #dtparam=spi=on

 # Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
 #dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

  # Additional overlays and parameters are documented 
  /boot/overlays/README

  # Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
  dtparam=audio=on
```

I followed the linked tutorial .but it didn't fix the issue. so I reversed back to the original config .This is my current config.txt

Comment: have you tried a monitor with HDMI?

Comment: yes ,I tried with multiple monitors

Comment: can you post your `config.txt` **in the question**

Comment: so, you didn't try anything in that tutorial ... since  all your `hdmi_force_hotplug` etc are still commented ... i.e. they start with `#` ... `o solve the problem you just have to uncomment (ie remove the sign # at the beginning) these lines and save the file`

Comment: I tried all of that in the tutorial. but none of that worked . that's why I commented those back

Comment: oh, ok - guess your HDMI is dead then

Comment: so , I guess I have to replace that HDMI

Comment: that's not what I meant ... I mean the HDMI output is dead, not the physical connector needs to be replaced

Comment: so , what should I do now ? 
and do you happen to have any idea why this happened?
I actually need to work with more pis .I am concerned that if I have done something wrong which led to this problem . I have to avoid doing that for other pis.

Comment: perhaps the hdmi to vga converter broke your pi?

Comment: maybe , I don't know for sure. and I haven't used pi before.